# PHP Xdebug Time-out connecting to client (Docker, VSCode, Ubuntu)

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to troubleshoot a Docker/PHP-Xdebug/VSCode environment on Ubuntu that has been working very well for the last few months. And now xdebug have trouble connecting to the client.

After entering the Docker with `docker exec --tty --interactive bw bash`

```
php -v
```

returns

```
PHP 7.2.14 (cli) (built: Feb  6 2019 05:10:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

while `php -m -c` lists Xdebug in the [Zend Modules] section.

Here is the .ini part

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_timeout = 500
```

Eveything in there is reflected accordingly in `phpinfo()` output.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  webserver:
    build: docker/apache
    container_name: bw
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
     - "8000:80"
    expose:
     - "9000"
    restart: always
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "log":true,
            "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/",
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }    ]
}
```

This is the tail of the xdebug.log

```
[156] Log opened at 2019-08-05 19:39:58
[156] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[156] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[156] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[156] I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.18.0.1:9000.
[156] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 500 ms). :-(
[156] Log closed at 2019-08-05 19:39:59
```

I strongly suspect my lack of Docker knowledge is the problem to make this work again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Wrong IP? It must be an IP of a computer where debug client (VSCode) is running as seen from PHP/webserver container. Try disabling `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0` and specify IP address manually (there is special host name for Docker) 2) Firewall? Make sure you can connect to VSCode while it listens for incoming Xdebug connections (use `telnet` or alike to test it) 3) What's your web server and how do you run PHP there? Apache module .. or php-fpm?

Comment: 4) Why do you need to expose "9000" in your docker-compose.yml ? Exposing means that connection to that port will be forwarded from host into container (so port is busy)... while it's VSCode that should be listening it .. and if something else is already occupied that port then VSCode may be unable to use it ...

Comment: Thank you kind sir. Turns out it was a firewall issue and I feel dumb because you made me realize I used the telnet command the other way around (from host to container) when troubleshooting. When I applied ```sudo ufw allow from any to any port 9000 proto tcp``` to the host, everything worked again. I have no idea why the rule disappeared from the firewall (or if it was there but more strict) as it was working a few weeks ago and I wish my firewall logs would go further back in time. Do you want to post an answer so I can accept it or should I?

Comment: Do it yourself (you can accept your own answers).

Answer (score 6):

Problem was with the firewall of the host. Can't really tell how/why the rule disappeared.
 I was probing the port with telnet the wrong way around and that led me thinking the firewall was letting traffic through. 
`ufw allow from any to any port 9000 proto tcp` on the host did in fact re-establish everything.

Comment: Thanks for this. After several hours of searching it turns out, that my firewall was the problem too.